# Specified cast not valid on reading, but inserting works?

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL table (see below) and I have two classes: `Incident` and `CircuitIncident`. `CircuitIncident` derives from incident and extends it with a trace_id reference (FK) and a severity enum which enumerates -1,0,1,2.

Using Linq to SQL I am able to **store** a CircuitIncident in the table. However, when reading the table using linq, I get the following exception at the "foreach" line:

```
var result = from eachIncident in db.Incidents.OfType<CircuitIncident>()
             where selectedTraceItems.Select(t => t.Id).Contains(eachIncident.CircuitTraceId)
             select eachIncident;

foreach(CircuitIncident circInc in result)
{
   //do something
}
```

> Test method SmartVisionUnitTests.IncidentViewModelTest.testLoad threw exception:  System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid..

I've already crosschecked the types et cetera, but I have no idea why I am able to store, but not to read the data. Does anybody have an idea why? Or does anybody know how to further narrow-down the root cause?

This is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.incident_tab 
( 
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    START real NOT NULL, 
    STOP real NOT NULL, 
    POS real NOT NULL, 
    SEVERITY smallint, 
    RACE_ID int NULL, 
    TimeStamp datetime NOT NULL, 
    TYPE char(1), 
    CONSTRAINT PK_incident_tab PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) 
) ; 

ALTER TABLE dbo.incident_tab ADD CONSTRAINT FK_INCIDENT_TRACE_ID FOREIGN KEY (TRACE_ID) REFERENCES dbo.trace_tab (ID) ;
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo,   IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
SmartVisionUnitTests.IncidentViewModelTest.testLoad() in Z:\SmartVision\SmartVision\SmartVisionTest\IncidentViewModelTest.cs: line 87
```

```
[Table(Name = "incident_tab")]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = "C", Type = typeof(CircuitIncident), IsDefault = true)]
public class Incident 
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [Column(IsDiscriminator = true)]
    private string TYPE;

    [Column(Name="POS")]
    public float Position { get; set; }

    public virtual float Size
    {
        get { return IncidentStop - IncidentStart; }
    }

    [Column(Name = "START")]
    public float IncidentStart { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "STOP")]
    public float IncidentStop { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "TIMESTAMP")]
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "ID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
}



public class CircuitIncident : Incident
{
    private int circuitTraceId = 0;

    [Column(Name="TRACE_ID")]
    public int CircuitTraceId
    {
        get { return circuitTraceId; }
        set { circuitTraceId = value; }
    }

    private AlarmStatusType severity = AlarmStatusType.Unknown;
    [Column(Name = "SEVERITY")]
    public AlarmStatusType Severity
    {
        get { return severity; }
        set { severity = value; }
    }
}
```

Thanks and Regards.

Andreas

Comment: Is it because of you `Type` Column?

Comment: Hm, what do you mean? The "type" column is my descriminator to determine what type to restore when using inheritance. When inserting it, it's getting filled correctly. What do you think could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself -> I tried to map the enum to a DB smallint field. If I use "int" on the DB it works. Still strang to me because accroding to the Microsoft documentation it should be possible to map enums to smallint.

Comment: By default C# enums are int. If you want a smallint in the DB you would have to declare your enum as short. public enum MyEnum : short { ... }

Comment: Andy, thanks a lot! That solved the issue and I don't need to waste space on the DB.